# How to make Windows 8 appear in a boot menu when dual-booting with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi, bootloader

I want to ask how to create GUI for choosing OS when booting my notebook.

I have Windows 8 preinstalled on my notebook, and I wish to have a dual boot system with Ubuntu,
However, after Ubuntu finishes installing, I cannot boot Windows 8.

Currently there is nothing to select to choices to boot Windows 8. Thus, I wish to have a quick switch between two operating systems.